# What is the reference name for early-binding of VBA SortedList?

Tags: vba, reference, sortedlist, early-binding

I have the following VBA code (late binding):

```
Dim myList As Object
Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
```

which I want to replace with this (early binding):

```
Dim myList As New SortedList
```

Has anyone succeeded with this? I suppose that A reference must be enabled. But what is the name of that reference?

Comment: Add `mscorlib.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably* the easiest way is to add it on openning:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
       .AddFromFile "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb"
       '.AddFromguid "{BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}", 2, 4
   End With
End Sub
```

This adds the `mscorlib.dll` to the references:

[image]

And then:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim myList   As SortedList
    Dim myList2  As New ArrayList ' as a bonus!
End Sub
```

---

From http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html

- The SortedList is not an element of the regular VBA-library.
- The SortedList is part of the library System.Collections.
- You can find the library in `\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb` or in a comparable directory
- In the VBEditor you can make a direct link to this library manually by checking mscorlib.dll in the References (Tools/references...)